# node: AWS s3 - How to see if a specific object exists (with IfModifiedSince)?

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

So, what I am doing in node is uploading an image to a tmp Bucket on S3 and then the lambda is resizing the image and saving it to a specific location (different bucket)..

now, what I would like is to get a feedback that lambda is done with manipulation.... normally I would know that just by checking if the resource is there yet, with:  [waitFor: objectExists](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#objectExists-waiter)

```
var params = {
  Bucket: 'STRING_VALUE', /* required */
  Key: 'STRING_VALUE', /* required */
};
s3.waitFor('objectExists', params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

All good and dandy... works the first time... but if the resources are already there, it does not work as intended.... so I needed to check it if the new version is there.... the amazon's docs says there is an option called: `IfModifiedSince` ... which takes a date...

so if I do something like this:

```
const date = new Date();
const minute = date.getMinutes();
date.setMinutes(minute - 1); // it's just for illustration purposes, not last code ;)

var params = {
  Bucket: PLAYESR_BUCKET,
  Key: file,
  IfModifiedSince: date,
};

s3.waitFor('objectExists', params, function(err, data) {

...
```

I get an error:

> ERROR NotFound: Resource is not in the state objectExists

```
{
  message: 'Resource is not in the state objectExists',
  code: 'ResourceNotReady',
  region: null,
  time: 2018-08-07T09:16:44.441Z,
  requestId: '6AFB651A109CD28F',
  extendedRequestId: 'xxx',
  cfId: undefined,
  retryable: true,
  statusCode: 404,
  retryDelay: 5000
}
```

Again, first time I do it, it works perfectly.
As soon as the file exists, I get this error

Comment: Note that the AWS Sdk will pool the resource for no longer than 100 seconds, and gives up afterwards. If your lambda function is taking longer then you might receive this error. So the question is; are you sure that your resource is being updated?

Comment: @RenatoGama, yes, my lambda takes 3-4s with init and all, tops... obviously I am checking cloudWatch log and it's all being processed and done....   as said... doing first time, the logic works.... if I do without the 'IfModifiedSince' options... it woks straight away on subsequential calls... but with this flag... when the object exists already, I get this error after ~3s.

Comment: You may be overlooking some implications of S3's consistency model... checking whether the object to has been overwritten yet may influence how long it takes for the new version of the object to become visible, just as checking for an object before creating it can delay its availability.  Have your Lambda function provide you with the version-id of the new object, instead, and use it.  It's there.  Don't poll the bucket.  That's unnecessary and ultimately provides no authoritative answer.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot: fair point.... I think it might be just that... that when I start overriding it it get's that status.... how would I interact with lambda instead of the bucket? the lambda triggers on it's own listening to the put event to the tmp bucket

Comment: Sorry, @DS_web_developer, for some reason I was thinking you were invoking the Lambda function, when it's actually an S3 event.  Those are async, so, yeah, no interaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Michae](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1695906/michael-sqlbot)l suggested I am not checking if the specific object exists (as he mentioned it might get an override flag)... I am creating a `${timestamp}.json` every time I create/override and check the existence of this one instead.... it might not be the most elegant but get's the job done